# Prevent (tomcat) web application from starting if configuration incomplete

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, startup

How do I set a "configuration check" on a web application startup (Tomcat or other) and if the condition is not met the application should not start.

Let's say the application require a the file /tmp/dummy to exist on the fs in order to start. So I have something like

```
public class TestConfig {

    public static void TestServerConfiguration()  {
        if (! new File("/tmp/dummy").exists()) {
            // don't start this web application ... 
        }
    }

}
```

Where should I include this test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with a [ServletContextListner](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).  As with the servlet answer, it will not stop Tomcat but it will prevent the web application from loading.  One advantage over the servlet answer is from the Javadoc:

> All ServletContextListeners are notified of context initialization before any filters or servlets in the web application are initialized.

As an example:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener; 

@WebListener
public class FileVerifierContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // verify that the file exists.  if not, throw a RuntimeException
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

Above assumes that your `web.xml` specifies a Servlet 3.0 or above environment (or that you don't have a `web.xml` at all):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
</web-app>
```

If you're using a lower servlet spec then you'll want to remove the `@WebListener` annotation and declare the listener in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app ...>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>
             com.example.package.name.FileVerifierContextListener 
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Eclipse does not like the @Override annotation in the listener. Otherwise, this is the solution I will adopt!

Comment: Why Eclipse does not like the @Override annotation in the listener?
Multiple markers at this line
 - The method contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent) of type FileVerifierContextListener must override a superclass method
 - implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener.contextInitialized
As expected, the code is ok (Maven build it without any problem). What am I  missing?
This is the solution I will adopt! I will confirm it tomorrow.

Comment: @StefanG - the `@Override` is totally not needed.  I'm not sure why Eclipse doesn't like it - perhaps because it's for an interface, not a class.  I'd remove it as it is not needed.

Comment: Found it. It was the "Compiler compliance level" ... was set to 1.5. I changed it to 1.8 and Eclipse is now happy.

Answer (score 0):

One idea (but there can be others) is to implement a servlet that will do this check and exit when the condition is false. You need to run it at the beginning of the context deployment with the adequate **load-on-startup** tag. The `web.xml` will then look like :

```
<servlet>
  <display-name>startup condition servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>startup condition</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.xxx.yyy.ConditionChecker</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>FILE_TO_CHECK</param-name>
    <param-value>/tmp/dummy</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

This servlet could execute `System.exit(1)` when the condition is not met (/tmp/dummy doesn't exist).
Please not this will kill the Tomcat. Not exactly stop the deployment process. If anyone want to fine tune this, you can edit my post.

Comment: The server must remain up. I was unable to workaround your idea but is not working.
The solution that stdunbar provided is the solution to my problem.